# Can't Connect to Azure Server from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, tcp

I can't connect SQL Server to Azure. When I try to connect I get this error:

[image]

How can I solve this?

> Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to mukdo.database.windows.net.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10060)
>
> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your IP is added in the firewall setting in Azure SQL. You can use 'Add client IP', if it's not added.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDx6z.png)

Answer (score 0):

My problem Solved After Change My Internet Connection